# Why is my sharing non-symmetrical?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

Home network, mixed wired and wi-fi connectivity, all on the same subnet (10.0.0.0/16). Two computers (1 wired, 1 wi-fi) running Win7 Ultimate x64, one running Windows 10 Pro. Also a MyBook World Edition wired.

No domain, no homegroup; it's an ad-hoc network. The user name and password on all three computers is the same.

I've turned on sharing for all the computers; the MyBook appears as network storage.

The two Windows 7 computers can access each other, the MyBook, and the Windows 10 computer. The Windows 10 computer can access the MyBook, but not the Windows 7 computers.

I had intended all the computers to be able to access each other. What have I overlooked?

Comment: By "can access" do you mean direct SMB access by `\\ip.add.re.ss` via File Explorer, or something else?

Comment: @grawity - By computer name, rather than IP address, but yes, in File Explorer/Windows Explorer

Comment: If the IP address works, it's a problem with local name resolution. If it also doesn't work, it's a problem with the file sharing service itself.

Comment: If it's the filesharing service, why can the two Windows 7 machines access each other?

Comment: Does that mean you're refusing to check the possibility?

Comment: @grawity - No; I will attempt to do further investigation when I am back at those computers - but I do like to understand what's going on, and I do like to be able to explain apparently anomalous behavior. If it's the filesharing service, why is it that it only affects the ability of the Windows 10 computer to access the Windows 7 computers? That falls under the heading of "anomalous behavior"; I wouldn't be as uncertain about the possibility if the two Win7 boxen were also not talking to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this, the Windows 10 computer stopped being able to access the MyBook, but the two Windows 7 computers could still access the Windows 10 computer. After a subsequent Windows 10 update was applied to the Windows 10 computer, the (expected to fail) attempt to access the MyBook complained that the firmware on the MyBook only supported the extremely deprecated SMB1, which was not enabled on the Windows 10 computer. Some research indicated that this was automatically uninstalled after 15 days from the update unless explicitly installed/configured. I installed SMB1, restarted the Windows 10 computer, and it can now access the MyBook *and* the Windows 7 computers, which is the state that I want this network to be in.

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows 7 machines, you should disable firewall.  The firewall prevents other machines from accessing your PC.

Here's a link to achieve this:
https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/disable-firewall

Comment: The two Windows 7 machines can access each other. It is only the Windows 10 machine that cannot access the Windows 7 machines.

Comment: Do you have firewall disabled on all machines?

Comment: I believe so. As indicated, Windows 7 computer #1 has no trouble accessing Windows 7 computer #2, and vice-versa. Both of these computers can access Windows 10 computer. The problem is that Windows 10 computer cannot access either Windows 7 computer.

Comment: (The firewalls were indeed off; see my separate answer for what turned out to be the solution.)